# Trying to deploy clickonce app to FTP site but getting FrontPage Server Extensions not installed Error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to deploy a WinForm app through clickonce using a ftp site on my dreamhost account. However, when I try to publish, I get the following error:

> Failed to connect to 'ftp://ftp.mydomain.com/client' with the following error: Unable to create the Web  site 'ftp://ftp.mydomain.com/client'. The components for communicating with FrontPage Server Extensions are not installed.

Here is my settings on the publish tab

> Publishing Folder Location: ftp://ftp.mydomain.com/client
>
> Installation Folder URL: http://ftp.mydomain.com/client

It seems that Visual Studio is not realizing I am publishing to a ftp site and not a site with FrontPage.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Visual Studio only supports publishing to web servers that have Frontpage Extensions installed, regardless of whether connecting via FTP or HTTP. If your host doesn't support them, you will have to publish to a local folder and then upload its contents using an FTP client.

UPDATE: The FrontPage extension components need to be installed on the machine you are DEVELOPING on (Used to publish). The server shouldn't matter--it's simply FTP. On your development system, go to control panel > add/remove programs > and repair "Microsoft Visual Studio Web Authoring Component". Depending on the version you have, you may need to repair VS2010, etc. This will reinstall the FP components on YOUR machine, allowing you to publish via FTP.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything like that there anymore in 'add/remove programs' for Windows 10 / VS 2015

Answer (score 2):

Do you recently installed Xamarin extensions xamarin.visualstudioInstall.msi ?
This is cause of stopped deployment component.
Check this discusion: 
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30406/bug-after-installing-xamarin

Removing 'Xamarin' from the uninstall/change a program fixed the issue for me.
After that VS 2013 and VS 2015 RC1 deployments started to work again.

Comment: Good catch! I think it might be the same issue for me. I can't uninstall just the Xamarin extension for VS, but rather need to uninstall the full Xamarin suite, which is impractical for daily use...

Answer (score 1):

what is worth of acknowledgment is the fact that Visual Studio 2010 may report such error due to problems with lacking RAM or after several sleep or hibernation phases with VS turned on. I experienced this with a perfectly well configured server which I have used for ages and done hundreds of publishes, the error came all of a sudden and the only medicine was a VS restart (or sometimes the whole machine's restart). Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228998.aspx), you'll have to add some custom content/mime types to your server for ClickOnce:

> If you are deploying a ClickOnce application from a Web server
>   other than IIS, you may experience a problem if the server is
>   returning the incorrect content type for key ClickOnce files, such as
>   the deployment manifest and application manifest. To resolve this
>   problem, see your Web server's Help documentation about how to add new
>   content types to the server, and make sure that all the file name
>   extension mappings listed in the following table are in place.

```
File name extension    Content type
===================    ===========================
.application           application/x-ms-application
.manifest              application/x-ms-manifest
.deploy                application/octet-stream
.msu                   application/octet-stream
.msp                   application/octet-stream
```

DreamHost allows you to [add custom mime types in a .htaccess file](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/MIME_Types#Adding_your_own_MIME_types).