# error creating application to be deployed with ClickOnce within our network via FTP

Tags: winforms, deployment, ftp, clickonce, fileshare

I am trying to set up an application to be deployed with ClickOnce within our network via FTP.  I am using C# in Visual Studio 2012 update 3.  In the Publish tab of the properties of the Winform app, I have a file share specified as the "Publishing Folder Location".  The "Installation Folder" is blank as well as the "Update Location" in the Application Updates page.  I have the "The application is available offline as well" radio button checked although I've tried it both ways.

The error message I get is:

Error   1   Failed to connect to '\servername\shares\DATA...\MyProjectPublishFolder\' with the following error: Unable to create the Web site '\servername\shares\DATA...\MyProjectPublishFolder'.  Unable to create the Web site location '\servername\shares\DATA...\MyProjectPublishFolder'.  Access is denied.

This implies it is trying to set up a web site.  I was wanting to deploy via FTP.  I cannot see any setting where I can specify FTP.

I found:

[Trying to deploy clickonce app to FTP site but getting FrontPage Server Extensions not installed Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755191/trying-to-deploy-clickonce-app-to-ftp-site-but-getting-frontpage-server-extensio)

but that fix didn't help.  Any other pointers are welcome.

Comment: I think I just had an epiphany!  I may have been totally confused about how ClickOnce worked.  This is my new assumption.  "Publish" means moving the application from the development environment to the location from which it will be distributed to users.  "Download" is the term where users get the application and move it into their personal space for execution.  In this paradigm, the developer can "Publish" the application using a web site, ftp server, or file path, but the user always "downloads" the application from a web server.  Please correct me if this is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was confused,  The developer can "Publish" the application using a Web Server, an FTP Server or a file path.  The user can "Download" the application using a Web Server, a File Share, or Removable Media (i.e.: DVD).